# Stuck in read-only all folders

Tags: windows, windows-10

I installed Windows 10 an all the folders are stuck in read only only applies to files in folder it's a square and I've tryed a few things I have read from Google and still can't get it to stop going back to read-only I can check it twice an a check mark pops up and makes the files read-only but so far it's just all of the folders

Comment: Are they *actually* read only... i.e. you can't rename them or make other changes?

Comment: Dat punctuation.. (I tried editing, one more is pending approval)

Comment: If you have an issue with just one application writing data or saving files, try adding an exception/exclusion in (Bit)Defender.

Answer (score 2):

In a folder's **Properties** dialog, the gray square in the Read-only checkbox ***IS NOT A STATUS INDICATOR***!
[image]
The checkbox is a tri-state switch that always displays the gray square when the dialog is displayed.

In addition:

- If a folder's read-only attribute is set, it doesn't affect file operations, it simply tells Windows to process the desktop.ini file -- most commonly used to assign a custom icon.
- If you want to quickly & accurately determine if files are read-only, add the **Attributes** column to an **Explorer** Details view.

Comment: @ggll : I think thiscomment belongs with the question & not my answer.